# Jetty VS Tomcat Maven Plugin - which one should I use?

Tags: java, maven, webserver, maven-jetty-plugin, maven-tomcat-plugin

I'm using Tomcat as my production server and I would like to use one of maven plugins in order to run the server from within the IDE. I saw that there are 2 plugins: **Tomcat maven plugin** and **Jetty maven plugin**.
What are the differences between the two? What are the prons and cons for each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always strive to make your development environment as close to production as possible. Jetty and Tomcat are both similarly easy to use with Maven, so if your production server is Tomcat I'd stick with Tomcat Maven Plugin.

Comment: If wanted, he could just add both to the pom. But indeed, if the production server is tomcat, then the tomcat-maven-plugin is the one that should be used to develop with. (preferably with the same version as the production server)

Comment: no answer regarding plugins differences but good enough for me to decide to use it